# Is there any way to use a list to represent procedure in a lambda caculus?

Tags: scheme, interpreter, sicp

There is a simple language called lambda calculus, which is a subset of scheme. It has only 4 expressions in the following.

```
exp : n (1 2 3)
 varref (variable reference)
 (lambda (x) body) (this is a procedure)
 (procedure argument) (this is a application which applies argument as real parameter to the procedure)
```

I'm writing an interpreter for this language with scheme. Scheme changes lambda expressions to scheme procedures, and I want to use a list to substitute it. Can anyone give me advice?

Answer (score 3):

Before you try to implement a lambda-calculus interpreter, you should understand the lambda calculus. I think your first step is to write down examples of lambda-calculus terms, and what they evaluate to. If that's something that's difficult, let me know; there are *plenty* of resources on the internet that will help you understand the terms of the lambda calculus and what they reduce to.

Here's one that looks plausible:

http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~udr/popl/handout1.pdf

along with

http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~udr/popl/handout2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

can you post some specific code that demonstrates the problem??
maybe i have totally misunderstood here , but i think you should have some sort of 
a reader for your language. when you fire it up and reads the lambda keyword it should 
call your "implementation".

check this great post out:
[lispy in chicken](http://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/lispy-in-chicken-self-evaluating-values/)